# React app calls a request in a loop when you open a page

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I am working with Strapi, which is built on React. I have a custom page which I try to show some data. However, when I open that page, the network tab and the debugger on terminal, show that a request is triggered in a loop. Since I am new to React, I am not sure what the problem is, but my guess is something with the `state`.

```
  const { pathType, id } = useParams();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const getData = () => request(`/${pathType}/${id}`, {method: 'GET'});
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(response => {
      return response;
    }).then(setData).catch(e => console.log(e));
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
```

And here is part of the debugger where shows the request from the `getData()`

```
[2020-08-31T10:33:30.644Z] debug OPTIONS /hostings/40 (1 ms) 204
[2020-08-31T10:33:30.942Z] debug GET /hostings/40 (297 ms) 200
[2020-08-31T10:33:30.949Z] debug OPTIONS /hostings/40 (0 ms) 204
[2020-08-31T10:33:31.241Z] debug GET /hostings/40 (291 ms) 200
....
```

Comment: `useEffect` without deps executed on every render of the component. `setData` inside it just calls the rerender. Pass an empty deps list `[]` to trigger the effect once on the mount.

Comment: Damn. You are right. I copy pasted the code from another file, which I missed the ending part with the dependencies.

Comment: I think if and empty deps is passed `[]` it will throw an error since `useEffect` in this case actually depends on `setData`

Comment: **Checked** and @NikitaMadeev was correct: you can simply add `[]` with no errors. but if `data` or any other state is used in `useEffect` then it will throw the error I was talking about

Comment: @akram-adel _it will throw an error_ No :) There will be no errors in any case. You will get incorrect application logic.

Comment: @NikitaMadeev You are correct :). I tried it in a sandbox and the only error/problem I got was from eslint complaining about *a missing dependency*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) on `useEffect`

> Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the DOM in React components are all examples of side effects.

Simply put: in your case, `useEffect` will be called every time you change the DOM through using `setData`

Now you want your `useEffect` to only `setData` only when `data` is empty. To do that you should add a condition to the `useEffect` as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data.lenght !== 0) return
  getData().then(response => {
    return response;
  }).then(setData).catch(e => console.log(e));
});
```

This will ensure that you `setData` only when `data` is empty.

---

You can check [Why effects run on each update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update)

And "quoting from react docs"

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument.

So `useEffect` should look like

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, []);
```